# Overwriting data when looping over Data flow tasks

Tags: ssis, powerbi

I have just started to study SSIS and just using the right vocabulary is making it difficult for me to find information on the internet.
I have been trying solve it by trying multiple things and reading as much as I could find.

With that said, I am having a problem with a Conditional Split when looping over files in Microsoft Visual Studio.
This is the conditional logic for the split *CustomerAmountCY < 0 || CustomerAmountCY == 0*

What it seems to do, is that it is working properly but each time in loops over a different file it overwrites.

I can untick a box so it doesn't overwrite, but then data from previous runs will still be there.

Is there any solution, where it overwrites previous runs data and not previous loops within the same run?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMX2Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkcUK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUGn.png)

Comment: I would start with simplifying your split logic to...   CustomerAmountCY <= 0

Comment: i am having trouble grasping what you are attempting to do. does this sound right??? Are you using a foreach to loop through files and then have a dataflow inside that foreach that has a conditional split in it?

Comment: If I had to guess with the information that I have available, I would guess that you are not updating the filepath variable properly. And that you are looping through the files in the foreach, but continue to process the same file and therefore it appears to not be updating on each foreach cycle. If that is done correctly, then make sure the filepath variable is mapped to the source.

Comment: I just modified the question with some images.

So there is 2 csv files that are looped over.
There is supposed to be errors in

1. Data Conversion
2. Conditional Split

The rest are supposed to be imported to the Data Warehouse.
The problem is that only the last of the two CSV files errors gets reported.

All the data, that is with no errors are imported correctly to the Data Warehouse.
If I turn of the tick "Overwrite data in the file", all the data is accurate however, the goal is that it is overwritten for the total debugging session, not for each loop